# Do Chilean passport holders get stamped entering the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, chilean-citizens

I am a Chilean passport holder and entering the US last time I didn't get my passport stamped as usual. Now I don't have proof of entry and don't know until when I can remain in the country.

Comment: You can obtain your proof of entry and duration of stay by retrieving your I-94 from the [CBP web site](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home).

Answer (score 3):

Not all entries to the US receive a passport stamp, especially if you use the electronic kiosks, and this is absolutely normal and fine.

Try looking up your information on the [official I-94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/). That will give you a record of your entry and will tell you how long you are allowed to stay.

Comment: Are you sure about this? To the best of my knowledge this only applies to US Citizens

Comment: Agreed, I visit the US regularly and have always been stamped in, even when using the kiosks.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen It can also happen to VWP passports, esp. at lax airports like MIA